# How can I search in other apps using global search

Tags: android

I'm new in Android programming and want to know if it's possible to search in other apps.

I mean, I want to find all notes which have #yellow inside the text.

Something like when I use the `QuickSearchBox`, but I don't want to open the notepad app. Instead I want to read this note inside my own app.
Or the same with the calendar, I want to find the next calendar entry which has #yellow in the description, and want to read the description in my app not in the calendar.

Is it possible to say global search, search for #yellow in calendar and give me the description of this entry?

The reason why I want to do it like this is I want to use an app which is already installed as an editor and store for my information.

Comment: It's (generally) up to individual application developers to make their content searchable.

Answer (score 0):

As an application I am sure you can make your info available for the `QuickSearchBox`.
The Android Documentation explains it [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/guide/topics/search/index.html), but I am not sure if you can use the `QuickSearchBox` inside your application.

First, I would start reading the [src code](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/GlobalSearch.git;a=summary) to understand how it works.